# Example of open manifold with no free integer homology non-homeomorphic to a ball

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, complex-manifolds, homology

I would like to state that if an open oriented even-dimensional (complex) manifold $M$ is such that $dim(H_k(M,\mathbb{Z}))=0$ for $k>0$, and 1 for $k=0$, then $M$ is homeomorphic to an open ball.

Is this true? Any ideas to work with? I am specially interested when $dim M >2$.

Comment: Freedman proved that every homology sphere bounfs a contractible 4 topological manifolds. Consider such a smooth one and take it's boundary out. Now the resultant manifold is not open ball.

Comment: Are there examples that are oriented?

Comment: Or simply remove a point from the Poincaré sphere, no? The result has nontrivial $\pi_1$ so it's certainly not homeomorphic to an open ball.

Comment: Does that kill the last homology group, Najib?

Comment: They are simply connected, so definitely oriented.

Comment: You are right, thank you very much.

Comment: So is there a general result for higher dimensions? $dimM=4$ is still a low-dimensional case.

Comment: @RGC Yes, it does kill the last homology group. For a higher dimensional example, just take the product with $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: Sure, stupid question. I was going to delete it.

Comment: There are contractible manifolds in every dimension at least 3 whose 'fundamental group at infinity' is not trivial, hence are not homeomorphic to a ball. It is a theorem of Stallings that any contractible manifold of dimension at least 5 with trivial fundamental group at infinity is homeomorphic to the ball, and a theorem of smoothing theory (unfortunately I don't know the names to cite here) that one may even say diffeomorphic there.

Comment: In dimension 2 every simply connected manifold is homeomorphic to either the 2-sphere or the ball.

Comment: Siebenmann! Not Stallings. My mistake.

Comment: @MikeMiller: it is actually Stallings. The reference is in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simply_connected_at_infinity. Siebenman of course also worked on this topic starting from his thesis, see http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.738.880&rep=rep1&type=pdf.

Comment: @Igor Thank you for the correction. I need to rely on something more precise than my weak memory!

Comment: In dimension 4  there are  the so called Mazur manifolds that are contractible  and not  diffeomorphic to the ball.   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mazur_manifold